# Cross domain session asp mvc in IE and old browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, session, cross-domain, session-cookies

Lets say that you have websites http://simple.com and a lot of subdomain, for example: http://first.simple.com, http://second.simple.com, http://last.simple.com.

Lets say that a user goes to last.simple.com and they get authenticated through the normal ASP .NET membership provider.

Then, from that site, they get sent to (redirection, linked, whatever works) site http://last.simple.com, and the intent of site http://first.simple.com was to pass that user to the other site as the status of isAuthenticated, so that the site http://last.simple.com does not ask for the credentials of said user again.

This worked in Chrome, Mozila, Opera(last versions), Safari, but don't worked in IE(all versions) and Opera( < v12.01).

**Scheme:**

> User, address(first.simple.com) -> post query to server, json answer,
>   if auth - redirect. May be problem in json(need use 'jsonp')?

**web.config**

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" protection="All" domain=".simple.com" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" />
</authentication>
</system.web>
```

**SessionService**

```
public void Authenticate(string username)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);

            var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(username, false);
            cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            cookie.Path = "/";
            cookie.Domain = domain;
            this.context.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
        }
```

**Global.asax**

```
 protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const string aspSessionid = "ASP.NET_SessionId";

        if (Context.Handler is IRequiresSessionState || Context.Handler is IReadOnlySessionState)
        {
            var cookie = Context.Request.Cookies[aspSessionid];
            if (cookie != null && Context.Session != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session.SessionID))
            {
                Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(aspSessionid, Session.SessionID) { Domain = domain, Path = "/", Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30) });
            }
        }
    }
```